# Extjs4 - Reloading store inside itemselector

Tags: extjs4

I have an itemselecor inside a grid, and i have an combobox that should reload only the store inside the itemselector( the value fields should remain intact)

Here is the itemselector

```
var grid = Ext.widget('form', {
        id: 'grid',
        title: '',
        width: 600,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        renderTo: 'itemselectorproduto',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'itemselector',
            name: 'itemselector',
            id: 'itemsel',
            anchor: '100%',
            imagePath: '/ux/images/',
            store: store,
            displayField: 'Nome',
            valueField: 'ID',
            value: vitrine,
            allowBlank: true,
            msgTarget: 'side'
        }]
    });
```

I tried to call the normal store.load(), but it have no effect and it shows no error on the console

If needed i will post more of the code, but i think just this should be enough

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the code if ItemSelector it doesn't look like it supports any changes in the store once it's been binded. It basically creates local copies of the data. And if you call bindStore method to assign different store - it will erase your selection.

You can always improve code in ItemSelector to allow such behavior. It should not be a problem. You can subscribe to datachanged or load event of the store when binding to it, and then handle situation when store data is changed.

Comment: here is how i reload the first store

store.load({ params: { descontoid: descontoid, categoriaid: null} });

this line works on a grid, but of course it oenst for the itemselector

Comment: How do you have itemselector inside the grid? Is it inside the cell or what?

Comment: i was using the itemselector as an item inside the grid, but it was a little confusing so i changed, no w i create the itemselector outside the grid and adds it on the grid as an item

Comment: but maybe im just not clear enough with my answer, what i wanted to know is if its possible to reload the store of the itemselector without killing the value field

Comment: That's my clearer :) Looking through the code if ItemSelector it doesn't look like it supports any changes in the store once it's been binded. It basically creates local copies of the data. And if you call bindStore method to assign different store - it will erase your selection.

Comment: Thanks, if you put this comment as an answer i will accept it

Anyways, what shoudl be the fix, im thinking about making two grids, and a button on the first that adds to the second(i dont care about the order)

Comment: Posted an answer and also added couple comments on how to improve situation to your needs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8539/discussion-between-beoulve-and-sha)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think the best way to do such thing is using ItemSelector`s "populateFromStore". Sure except of extending item selector. In case of extending you should look on the "onBindStore" function of the ItemSelector.

```
onBindStore: function(store, initial) {
    var me = this;

    if (me.fromField) {
        me.fromField.store.removeAll()
        me.toField.store.removeAll();

        // Add everything to the from field as soon as the Store is loaded
        if (store.getCount()) {
            me.populateFromStore(store);
        } else {
            me.store.on('load', me.populateFromStore, me);
        }
    }
}
```

So as you see in case of the empty store it hooks to the load event. And it should be like this:

```
    onBindStore: function(store, initial) {
    var me = this;

    if (me.fromField) {
        me.fromField.store.removeAll()
        me.toField.store.removeAll();

        me.store.on('load', me.populateFromStore, me);
        // Add everything to the from field as soon as the Store is loaded
        if (store.getCount()) {
            me.populateFromStore(store);
        }
    }
}
```